# I get notified for edits on a deleted post

Tags: bug, user-interface

I clicked "follow" on [a curious post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/posts/39657/revisions) yesterday. It was deleted, but apparently it's still getting edited, because I have received multiple alerts in my inbox.

[image: My recent inbox notifications, 3/4 about GOLD VALUE]

I don't have enough reputation to view the deleted post, so I get a 404 when I click the notification.

Thus I can't unfollow the question, either!

This is mainly a curiosity (please don't manually unfollow it on my behalf even if you can - if nothing else it allows for future troubleshooting) but surely also a bug in how the follow logic is implemented.  Or is there a way to unfollow this post without visiting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now [status-fixed](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-fixed) as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366525/169312
in the sense that you can now unfollow deleted posts even if you don't have enough rep to otherwise see them.

Answer (score 4):

According to the answer to [Cannot unfollow locked post from Following tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349629/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange, you should be able to unfollow the post from the [Following tab in your user profile](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=following).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work; it says I'm not following any posts.

Comment: Too bad, perhaps because you don't have the privilege to see the post.

Comment: Posted a separate bug report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354289/cant-unfollow-deleted-post